# Is there an existing Documentation/Forum/Article for implementing Angular 7 to and existing Symfony 3 project?

Tags: angular, twig, symfony-3.3

I am trying to upgrade our existing Symfony 3 project with Twig by implementing Angular as Framework for Frontend

I am running it on Linux 18.04 LTS, I've tried different installation process on the internet, but those did was to create new bundle outside the Symfony Bundles.

I expect like installing it and will merge with the existing Symfony Bundles, not creating another Bundle for Angular only. It should be Symfony, Angular, Twig in one Bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular 2+ is a framework, not a library which allows you to integrate with other framework and make it work as your main objective is to make a single bundle of symfony, angular and twig which is not possible without any hack.

I did the same but with laravel framework might be this work with symfony as well (not sure). what I did is point all routes to the same blade (in your case twig template) and in this template, I used the angular tag with build bundles of angular.

so whenever I hit any page laravel execute the same blade (template) with angular code.

But in the end, I end up with writing unnecessary extra code and efforts.

Comment: Thanks jude, I ended up the same way writing bunch of unnecessary codes. What I will do now is try to find another way to build a website using these 3 tools.